# Sum inside cvx objective function

Tags: optimization, iteration, convex-optimization, cvx

I have the following objective function:

[image]

I am not sure how to write it in cvx.

This is my try:

```
cvx_begin sdp
variable Q(T,n,N)
%variable X_0T*Q(:,:,N) symmetric
obj = trace(X_0T*Q(:,:,N));
for j = 1:N-1
    obj= obj + trace(X_0T*Q(:,:,j)))
    subject to
     [X_0T*Q(:,:,j+1)-eye(n), X_1T*Q(:,:,j); Q(:,:,j)'*X_1T', X_0T*Q(:,:,j)] >= 0;
      X_0T*Q(:,:,1) >= eye(n);

end
minimize(obj)
cvx_end

K_cvx_df = -U_01T*Q(:,:,N)*pinv(X_0T*Q(:,:,N))
```

However, when I try to solve it for N going to infinity, it gives me a different solution from the infinite time horizon case, which is

```
 cvx_begin sdp
variable Q(T,n)
minimize( trace(X_0T*Q))
subject to
    [X_0T*Q-eye(n), X_1T*Q; Q'*X_1T', X_0T*Q] >= 0
 cvx_end
 K_cvx_d = -U_01T*Q*inv(X_0T*Q)
```